# I know I can't directly get a dictionary table length in Lua... but can I know at least if it has any entry or not?

Tags: lua, lua-table

As summary states... Lets say I want to quickly know if a table is empty or has been filled with some hash entries, is there a simpler and generic (I mean, not having to resort to check if certain entry exists) way than having to parse the table to simply know this? Thanks.

Comment: Totally, as well as Jack's answer, although there is very good extra info there to complete, so thank you too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [next](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-next) function to do this. If the table `t` is empty, then `next(t)` will return nil. Otherwise, `next(t)` will return the first index and the associated value.

```lua
local t1 = {}
local index1, value1 = next(t1)
print(index1, value1) -- nil    nil

local t2 = {a = "b", c = "d"}
local index2, value2 = next(t2)
print(index2, value2) -- c  d
```

Note that the order that `next(t)` accesses the table in is arbitrary. In the case of `t2`, it happened to choose index "c" first.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you! I didn't know about such function and I think it's going to be extremely useful not only for this kind of cases but surely others... About the arbitrary order, I wouldn't have expected a different behavior (for the nature of Lua dictionaries), but it's something one may have in mind in some cases, of course. Well, thanks again for letting me know and greetings!